# Need some help identifying the HTML tag that will allow me to pull all the relevant headlines, links and img URL's. My code is currently displaying 1

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I used Request library to access the website and BeautifulSoup to parse the html .I would like my scraper to be able to scrape at least 4 headlines with the links and Image URL from the website. I know its the HTML tag and I have failed to locate which tag. I have uploaded what I have done so far. The code is displaying the 1st headline, URL's, headline links.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#user agent to facilitates end-user interaction with web content**

headers = [''Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101'
]

#identifying website to be scraped*

source = request.get('https://www.jse.co.za/').text

#print(source) - verifying if HTLM for the page

soup = BeautifulSoup(source ,'lxml')# html parser
#print(soup.prettify)- to check if HTML has been parsed.

for item in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'view-content row row-flex'})[0:4]:# indexing
   text = item.find('h3'  {'class':'card__title'}).text .strip()
   img =  item.find('img' {'class': 'media__image })
   link= item.find('a')
   article_link = link.attrs('href')
   print('Article Headline')
   print(text)
   print('IMAGE URL')
   print(img['data-src']
   print('LINK TO ARTICLE')
   print(article_link)
   print()
```

output

````
# looking at output of 4 headlines
ARTICLE HEADLINE
South Africa offers investment opportunities to Asia Pacific investors
# looking at output of at least 4 Image URL's 
IMAGE URL
/sites/default/files/styles/standard_lg/public/medial/images/2021-06/Web_Banner_0.jpg?h=4ae650de&itok=hdGEy5jA
# I was hoping to scrape at least 4 links
LINK TO ARTICLE
/news/market-news/south-africa-offers-investment-opportunities-asia-pacific-investors







```
````

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ and __scraper__ not scrap or scrapper. ‘To scrap’ and scrapping, scrapped, scrapper are about throwing things away like rubbish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at that JSE site, they are using the `article` tag to list each of the news items, with the `card` class also, so I would suggest using `for article in soup.find_all('article')` to split up by those, then within that get each of the inner items.

Update: fully working example.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base_url = 'https://www.jse.co.za'

source = requests.get(base_url).text
print("Got source")

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
print("Parsed source")

articles = soup.find_all("article", class_="card")
print(f"Number of articles found: {len(articles)}")

for article in articles:
    print("----------------------------------------------------")

    headline = article.h3.text.strip()
    link = base_url + article.a['href']
    text = article.find("div", class_="field--type-text-with-summary").text.strip()
    img_url = base_url + article.picture.img['data-src']

    print(headline)
    print(link)
    print(text)
    print("Image: "+ img_url)
```

Runnable [here](https://replit.com/@LukeStorry/68018961)

Comment: Let me try it out and see if it works. So its changing  the *for article* and **headlines**

Comment: Sorry I got no output after running your suggested changes

Comment: What went wrong? Have you tried getting articles, whats inside that? If you're printin thing then you haven't "got no output", if its not what you expected then how far off is it?

Comment: @coja56 These were just suggestions, when I have a bit more time I'll spin up some code and have a go

Comment: @coja56 I've written some actually working code now :)